# Cannot reload tableview within the amplify.api.query function

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify to load data to my app. When I load a paginated list, I'm appending elements from a stored list onto my data model array. However, as the loading of the elements takes a bit of time, I either have to call `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of the `amplify.api.query` function in a completion handler or call `tableView.reloadData()` directly after I call `events.append()` within the `amplify.api.query` function. However, `amplify.api.query` neither has a completion handler nor lets me put `tableView.reloadData()` within the function itself, as every time I try to and I run the app, an error pops up saying that "UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only." I want the tableview to load upon the `UIViewController`'s startup. How should I do this?

```
func listFirstPage(finished: () -> Void) {

        Amplify.API.query(request: .paginatedList(Items.self, where: nil, limit: 1000)) { item in
            switch item {
            case .success(let result):
                switch result {
                case .success(let items):
                   
                    self.currentPage = items
                    self.events.append(contentsOf: items)
                    print(self.items)
                    self.AddItemTableView.reloadData()
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Got failed event with error \(error)")
            }
        }
        
          
    }
```

Comment: Ask not what tableView.reloadData can do for you.  Ask what you can do for asynch data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.AddItemTableView.reloadData()
}
```